# How to show mongoose schema validation error message at client side in next js app?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, next.js

Creating a user registration form in nextjs app and Mongodb. I created user schema with username as email address with unique: true flag and cutom validation error message. RegisterForm where I am trying to log the custom error message from surSchema. However I am getting the error: 400 and not the custom message...

User Schema:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    company: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
    },
    userName: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        lowercase: true,
        unique: true,
        required: "Email address is required",
        validate: {
            validator: function (v) {
                return this.model("User")
                    .findOne({ userName: v })
                    .then((user) => !user);
            },
            message: (props) => `${props.value} is already registered`,
        },
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
    },
    subscriptionPlan: {
        type: String,
    },
    joiningDate: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now,
    },

    expiry: { type: Date },

    address: {
        type: String,
    },
    country: {
        type: String,
    },
    mobile: {
        type: Number,
    },
});

UserSchema.pre("save", async function (next) {
    if (this.isModified("password")) {
        const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
        this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, salt);
        next();
    } else {
        next(new Error("failed to encrypt password"));
    }
});

UserSchema.methods.comparePassword = async function (password, next) {
    const comparison = bcrypt.compare(password, this.password);
    if (!comparison) {
        return {
            isMatch: false,
            comparison: comparison,
        };
    } else {
        return {
            isMatch: true,
            comparison: comparison,
        };
    }
};

module.exports = mongoose.models.User || mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

API: Users/index

```
import dbConnect from "../../../util/dbConnect";
import User from "../../../models/user";

dbConnect();

export default async (req, res) => {
    const { method } = req;

    switch (method) {
        case "GET":
            try {
                const users = await User.find({});
                res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: users });
            } catch (error) {
                res.status(400).json({ success: false });
            }
            break;
        case "POST":
            try {
                const size = req.body.length;
                if (size > 1) {
                    const inputData = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
                        inputData.push(req.body[i]);
                    }
                    const users = await User.insertMany(inputData);
                    res.status(201).json({ success: true, data: users });
                } else {
                    const users = await User.create(req.body);
                    res.status(201).json({ success: true, data: users });
                }
            } catch (error) {
                return res.status(400).json({ success: false });
            }

            break;
        case "DELETE":
            try {
                const users = await User.deleteMany({ _id: req.body.ids });
                res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: users });
            } catch (ex) {
                if (ex.response && ex.response.status === 400) {
                    const errors = ex.response.data.errors;
                    this.setState({ errors });
                }
            }
            break;

        default:
            res.status(400).json({ success: false });
            break;
    }
};
```

RegisterForm:

```
import dbConnect from "../../../util/dbConnect";
import User from "../../../models/user";

dbConnect();

export default async (req, res) => {
    const { method } = req;

    switch (method) {
        case "GET":
            try {
                const users = await User.find({});
                res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: users });
            } catch (error) {
                res.status(400).json({ success: false });
            }
            break;
        case "POST":
            try {
                const size = req.body.length;
                if (size > 1) {
                    const inputData = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
                        inputData.push(req.body[i]);
                    }
                    const users = await User.insertMany(inputData);
                    res.status(201).json({ success: true, data: users });
                } else {
                    const users = await User.create(req.body);
                    res.status(201).json({ success: true, data: users });
                }
            } catch (error) {
                return res.status(400).json({ success: false });
            }

            break;
        case "DELETE":
            try {
                const users = await User.deleteMany({ _id: req.body.ids });
                res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: users });
            } catch (ex) {
                if (ex.response && ex.response.status === 400) {
                    const errors = ex.response.data.errors;
                    this.setState({ errors });
                }
            }
            break;

        default:
            res.status(400).json({ success: false });
            break;
    }
};
```

I am getting error for duplicate User name as below;

[enter image description here][1]

But I want to display error from userName - validator message from schema....

Error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrQVl.png

Comment: You are checking wrong console. See your terminal for errors. API runs on the server not on the browser. Add `console.error(error)` in your catch statements.

Comment: Yes I checked in terminal and it shows the validationError with custom message as I set in the Schema... However I want to notify client side with alert message that user is already registered. But I am not sure how to do it....

Comment: Check what the error is on server side. And where you are sending success:false, also send a message key telling what went wrong to the client. the client can then notify the user with the message accordingly. Something like this:  ```if (error.name == 'ValidationError') { return res.status(400).json({ success: false, message: 'Please check the data you have inserted' }) }```

Comment: Thank You @brc-dd  for the support. your valuable suggestion helped me to find out the solution

Answer (score 0):

Achieved client side alert message by doing following changes:

API: users/index:

```
catch (error) {
                if (error.name == "ValidationError") {
                    return res.status(400).json({
                        success: false,
                        message: "Username already registered! Try logging in",
                    });
                }
```

RegisterForm:

```
if (!res.ok) {
                throw new Error(res.json().then((error) => alert(error.message)));
            }
```